# In what part of execution order are Owner Based Sharing rules evaluated?

Tags: apex, sharing, ownership, order-of-execution, criteria-based-sharing

Salesforce do specify that *Criteria* Based Sharing is evaluated quite late in the execution context, but the documentation makes no reference to *Owner* Based Sharing:

From [salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm):

> 1) Loads the original record from the database or initializes the record for an upsert.
>
> 2) Loads the new record field values from the request and overwrites the old values.
>
> 3) Executes all before triggers.
>
> . . .
>
> 19) **Executes Criteria Based Sharing evaluation.**
>
> 20) Commits all DML operations to the database.
>
> 21) Executes post-commit logic, such as sending email.

So, in what part of the execution order does *Owner* Based Sharing evaluation occur?

Answer (score 1):

Since they are owner based, they don't have to be evalated during the sequence.
Criteria based however, are evaluated since the criteria need to be revisited for evaluating the sharing.

PS: I think by now you would have got the answer, but still for others posting this.